# lowerbound confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, means, confidence-interval

An employee who wanted to describe the strength of materials performed a sample of 14 measurements. He assumed that these were independent measurements all from the same normal distribution (the parameters of which are unknown). He correctly set up the 95% confidence interval for the mean strength and arrived at the interval [113.42; 124.16]. His supervisor looked at the work, but then said she preferred a 99% confidence interval. Enter the lower bound of this 99% confidence interval. Round up to two decimal places.

Please some can help me how I can calculate this question for example how S must be done?

Comment: How are the bounds on a $95\%$ confidence interval calculated?

Comment: The sample mean is in the middle of the 95% confidence interval, so it is Xn = (113.42 + 124.16) / 2 = 118.79

Comment: no one who understand this question.

Comment: And how do you determine how wide the confidence interval is?

Comment: Outline: The given CI is of the form $\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$ where you can find from a t table that $t^* = 2.160.$ and thus find $S/\sqrt{14}$ and $\bar X.$ Then you need to find the appropriate $t^*$ for a one-sided 99% lower bound $\bar X - t^*S/\sqrt{14}.$ It is permitted to Answer one's own Question. Maybe you can do that.